# Has any treatment based on applying exogenous BMP-2 to the wound site been shown to be useful to treat tendinopathies?

Tags: tendinopathy, treatment, tendons

The 2011 study {1} showed that:

> Our findings indicate that it is possible to significantly improve tendon healing by applying exogenous BMP-2 to the wound site, inferring that this protein could be developed as a potential therapeutic reagent for the treatment of damaged tendons.

Has any treatment based on applying exogenous BMP-2 to the wound site been shown to be useful to treat tendinopathies?

---

References:

- {1} Li, Z., Shen, X., Cao, L. et al. Chin. Sci. Bull. "Bone morphogenetic protein 2 improves patellar tendon healing by promoting migration and proliferation of tenocytes".(2011) 56: 1361. https://doi.org/10.1007/s11434-011-4438-7